# scp hangs at 100%, before finishing

Tags: linux, scp

my scp commands do hang at 100% before the finish (some seconds), The output I get using -vvv is this:
http://paste.pocoo.org/show/137504/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

In my experience this is just because the % indicates how much data has been queued up to send to the remote server, and unless you're on a fast link you'll have to wait a little while for the network to actually finish sending it.

Comment: oddly enough that only happens for some servers, and my network connection is the same for all of them…

Comment: Are those servers on the same network too? If not, they may each have varying down-link capacities and speeds.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the files may be integrity checked before the transfer completes, all the connections and open buffers have to close as well.