# scp after 100% takes a long time

Tags: linux, scp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [scp hangs at 100%, before finishing](https://superuser.com/questions/33928/scp-hangs-at-100-before-finishing)

I scp a file from my local machine to an amazon machine. The file get transfered fine, but after it gets to 100% transfered it takes a long time to terminate.

Any particular reason. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

If the directory has a large number of files in it, then there can be a lengthy delay while this list is re-transferred.